# Use sf polygon object as window in spatstat

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf, spatstat

Hello all potential helpers,

I have a `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` object obtained from the `tigris` package and I would like to use it as a polygonal window in the creation of a `ppp` object. Here is what I tried:

```
# Needed packages
library(spatstat)
library(sf)

# Download geospatial data for Lee county in Alabama (home of the great Auburn University by the way!)
county <- tigris::county_subdivisions(state = "Alabama", county = "Lee")

# The polygon of Lee county is subdivided, so I convert it to a single polygon after converting it to an sf object
county_sf <- st_as_sf(county)
county_one <- st_union(county_sf)

# A quick plot of the object outputs what I am expecting
plot(county_one)
```

[image: Lee County, AL]

```
# Now I create a planar point pattern and I use county_one as the window
p <- ppp(x = -85.4, y = 32.5, window = as.owin((county_one)))

# But the plot here shows that the window is just a rectangle and not the polygon :(
plot(p)
```

[image: ppp object]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is just in the making. See https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1233 for more information

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note: I have edited this answer to contain full details.**

As @TimSalabim mentions this is under way in `sf`, but until then you have to
go through the old `sp` classes such as `SpatialPolygons`. Use something like
`as_Spatial` in `sf` and then load `maptools` and use `as.owin` or
`as(x, "owin")` on the `Spatial` object.

Furthermore, you can only use coordinates in planar (projected) space with
`spatstat` and not coordinates on the curved surface of the earth. You have
to project to a relevant planar coordinates system. Maybe <epsg.io/6345> is
usable in this case. To project to this coordinate system use
`sf::st_transform(county_one, crs = 6345)`. Afterwards you convert to
`Spatial` and then `owin`. *Note: Choosing the relevant projection is a
science, and I don’t know much about it, so do a bit of research if you want
to make sure you don’t get too distorted results.*

Specifically with the original example you can do:

```r
# Needed packages
library(spatstat)
#> Loading required package: spatstat.data
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> Loading required package: rpart
#> 
#> spatstat 1.62-2       (nickname: 'Shape-shifting lizard') 
#> For an introduction to spatstat, type 'beginner'
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.2, PROJ 6.2.1
library(maptools)
#> Loading required package: sp
#> Checking rgeos availability: TRUE
library(tigris)
#> To enable 
#> caching of data, set `options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)` in your R script or .Rprofile.
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tigris'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     plot

county <- county_subdivisions(state = "Alabama", county = "Lee", class = "sf", progress_bar = FALSE)
county_one <- st_union(county)
plot(county_one)
```

[image]

```r
county_flat <- st_transform(county_one, crs = 6345)
plot(county_flat)
```

[image]

```r
county_owin <- as.owin(as_Spatial(county_flat))
```

100 random points in the county:

```r
p <- runifpoint(100, win = county_owin)
plot(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `sf` function is `as_Spatial`. I unfortunately get this error when I use `as.owin`: `Error in maptools:::as.owin.SpatialPolygons(county_sp) : Only projected coordinates may be converted to spatstat class objects`.

Comment: You can only use coordinates in planar (projected) space with `spatstat` and not coordinates on the curved surface of the earth. You have to project to relevant coordinates system. Maybe https://epsg.io/6345 is relevant. To project to this coordinate system use `sf::st_transform(county_one, crs = 6345)`. Afterwards you convert to `Spatial` and then `owin`. Note choosing the relevant projection is a science, and I don't know much about it, so do a bit of research if you want to make sure you don't get too distorted results.

Answer (score 1):

just want to note here that coercion methods for sf classes are now registered (if that's the right word) by the sf package. I don't fully understand the R magic that finds methods, but it does work.

```
library(sf)
library(spatstat)

> methods(as.owin)
 [1] as.owin.boxx                    as.owin.data.frame              as.owin.default                 as.owin.distfun                
 [5] as.owin.dppm                    as.owin.funxy                   as.owin.im                      as.owin.influence.ppm          
 [9] as.owin.kppm                    as.owin.layered                 as.owin.leverage.ppm            as.owin.linfun                 
[13] as.owin.linnet                  as.owin.lintess                 as.owin.lpp                     as.owin.lppm                   
[17] as.owin.msr                     as.owin.MULTIPOLYGON*           as.owin.nnfun                   as.owin.owin                   
[21] as.owin.POLYGON*                as.owin.ppm                     as.owin.ppp                     as.owin.psp                    
[25] as.owin.quad                    as.owin.quadratcount            as.owin.quadrattest             as.owin.rmhmodel               
[29] as.owin.sf*                     as.owin.sfc*                    as.owin.sfc_MULTIPOLYGON*       as.owin.sfc_POLYGON*           
[33] as.owin.SpatialGridDataFrame*   as.owin.SpatialPixelsDataFrame* as.owin.SpatialPolygons*        as.owin.tess                   
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

So, assuming you have properly projected your data (as noted by @Ege Rubak), calling `as.owin` directly should work:

```
library(tigris)

county <- county_subdivisions(state = "Alabama", 
                              county = "Lee", 
                              class = "sf", 
                              progress_bar = FALSE)

county <- st_union(county)

county <- st_transform(county, crs = 6345)

window <- as.owin(county)

plot(window)
```

[image]