# vector shp point to ppp spatstat with polygon windows

Tags: polygon, spatial, point, spatstat

I always get error to this

```
# polygon that to be window
neighborhoods <- st_read("neighborhoods/neighborhoods.shp")

# convert CRS to planar projection as recommended by (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597078/use-sf-polygon-object-as-window-in-spatstat)
neighborhoods_3857 <- st_transform(neighborhoods, crs = 3857)

# point that to be PPP spatstat
trees <- st_read("trees/trees.shp")

# convert to planar projection
trees_3857 <- st_transform(trees, crs = 3857)
```

The problems, the "trees_3857" doesn't have dataframe columns that represent in EPSG3857 coordinates, so Feature column of "trees_3857" doesn't have x and y columns that respect to EPSG 3857

```
q <- ppp(x=?, y=?, win=neighborhoods_3857)
```

what I have done but error

```
z <- as.ppp(trees_3857, win=neighborhoods_3857)
Error in as.ppp.sf(trees_3857, win = neighborhoods_3857): unused argument (win = neighborhoods_3857)
Traceback:
```

You can get the data freely from datacamp.

```
https://assets.datacamp.com/production/repositories/738/datasets/96a72364e69d872645038b3a6dc7c0dbcb1114d6/neighborhoods.zip

https://assets.datacamp.com/production/repositories/738/datasets/08a3684dc4d538d59ba051a64a834166883ab5d1/trees.zip
```

Comment: Please add example data that others can actually read in and reproduce the error. Also `as.ppp` from `sf` doesn't have an argument `win`, so you should assign the correct window after converting to `ppp`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is the data which you can get from datacamp. Just right click in this link below, then click "save as linked content as"

https://assets.datacamp.com/production/repositories/738/datasets/96a72364e69d872645038b3a6dc7c0dbcb1114d6/neighborhoods.zip

https://assets.datacamp.com/production/repositories/738/datasets/08a3684dc4d538d59ba051a64a834166883ab5d1/trees.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you're wanting to transform your data into an object of class `"ppp"` from the `spatstat` package, the error message indicates that the problem originated in the function `as.ppp.sf` which is part of the `sf` package.

The error message says `unused argument: win` which means that the function did not recognise or accept the argument `win`.

Just to make it more challenging, the function `as.ppp.sf` is not documented and is not visible... By typing `sf:::as.ppp.sf` we can see the function body and figure out that the function has only one argument, so it does not accept any window information.

This is not the way the generic function `as.ppp` is designed to work in the `spatstat` package, so if you looked for `help(as.ppp)` in `spatstat`, it's not surprising that you got confused.

The best solution is (as Ege Rubak suggests) to convert the point coordinates and then add the window information:

```
z <- as.ppp(trees_3857)
Window(z) <- as.owin(neighborhoods_3857)
```

The conversions `as.ppp` and `as.owin` will be executed using code in `sf` so I can't guarantee they will work. The assignment `Window(z) <-` will be executed in `spatstat` code, see `help("Window<-.ppp")`.

Comment: Can I upvote you twice? Your code worked well.

z <- as.ppp(trees_3857)
Window(z) <- as.owin(neighborhoods_3857)